# How to fix CrawlSpider redirection?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a CrawlSpider for this site: http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php
This is my code:

```
import urlparse
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from project.items import Product
import re



class ShamsStoresSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "shamsstores2"
    domain_name = "shams-stores.com"
    CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1

    start_urls = ["http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php"]

    rules = (
            #categories
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="categories_block_left"]/div/ul/li/a'), unique=False), callback='process', follow=True),
            )

    def process(self,response):
        print response
```

This is the response I get when I use scrapy crawl shamsstores2

```
2013-11-05 22:56:36+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6081
2013-11-05 22:56:41+0200 [shamsstores2] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php> (referer: None)
2013-11-05 22:56:42+0200 [shamsstores2] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?id_category=14&controller=category&id_lang=1> from <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?controller=category&id_category=14&id_lang=1>
2013-11-05 22:56:42+0200 [shamsstores2] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?id_category=14&controller=category&id_lang=1> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_CLASS)
2013-11-05 22:56:43+0200 [shamsstores2] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?id_category=13&controller=category&id_lang=1> from <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?controller=category&id_category=13&id_lang=1>
2013-11-05 22:56:43+0200 [shamsstores2] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?id_category=12&controller=category&id_lang=1> from <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?controller=category&id_category=12&id_lang=1>
2013-11-05 22:56:43+0200 [shamsstores2] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?id_category=10&controller=category&id_lang=1> from <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?controller=category&id_category=10&id_lang=1>
2013-11-05 22:56:43+0200 [shamsstores2] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?id_category=9&controller=category&id_lang=1> from <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?controller=category&id_category=9&id_lang=1>
2013-11-05 22:56:44+0200 [shamsstores2] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?id_category=8&controller=category&id_lang=1> from <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?controller=category&id_category=8&id_lang=1>
2013-11-05 22:56:44+0200 [shamsstores2] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?id_category=7&controller=category&id_lang=1> from <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?controller=category&id_category=7&id_lang=1>
2013-11-05 22:56:44+0200 [shamsstores2] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?id_category=6&controller=category&id_lang=1> from <GET http://www.shams-stores.com/shop/index.php?controller=category&id_category=6&id_lang=1>
2013-11-05 22:56:44+0200 [shamsstores2] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

it hits the links extracted from the rule, those links redirect to some other links then it stops without executing the function: process.
I can fix this by using a base spider, but can I fix it and still use a crawlspider ?

Comment: Is the solution below worked for you ? if not, I would be eager to know of the alternate solution which worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not redirection. Scrapy does as server suggest goes to the alternate location and fetches the page from there.

The problem your "restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="categories_block_left"]/div/ul/li/a')" for all the visited pages, it simply extracts the same set of 8 urls and filters them as duplicate.

P.S. The only thing I don't understand is why scrapy gives message for only one page. I will update if I find the reason.

Edit : refer  github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/request.py

Basically first the request gets queued and the finger print is stored. Next the redirected url is generated and when checked whether it is duplicate by comparing the fingerprints, scrapy finds the same fingerprint. Scarpy finds the same fingerprint because as cited in the example, as per scrapy, reordered query strings of the redirected url and original url is same.

Kind of 'exploit'  solution

```
rules = (
    #categories
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@id="categories_block_left"]/div/ul/li/a') ), callback='process', process_links= 'appendDummy', follow=True),

    def process(self,response):
        print 'response is called'
        print response

    def appendDummy(self, links):
        for link in links:
            link.url = link.url +"?dummy=true"
        return links
```

Because server ignores the appended dummy in the redirected url, we kind of fool the finger print to treat the original request and redirected request to treat different.

One more solution will be to you yourself reorder the query parameters in the process_link callback(in the example appendDummy).

And other solutions might be to override finger_print to differentiate these type urls( I think it will be wrong in general cases, may be fine over here) or simple finger print based on url( again only for this case).

Please let me if the solution worked for you or not.

P.S. scrapy's behaviour of treating the re-ordered and orginal url is right. I don't understand whats the reason of the server for redirecting to reordered query string.

Comment: it's not only one page, you can find in the log that the pages are different, each one has a different ?id_category number

Comment: I don't really get the problem of the xpath? the 8 urls are different, why does scrapy filters them as duplicates?

Comment: a url redirects to another url, so scrapy filters it as a duplicate, how to stop it form filtering them using a crawlspider?

Comment: sorry for all these comments, it gives one message for only one page because it only shows the first duplicate: "no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_CLASS)"

Comment: Sorry, If my answer was not clear enough. Did you fixed your problem or still working with it ?

Comment: I'm still working with it, please tell me if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Did you understood the problem I sighted and can you tell me what links you are crawling and what data you are gathering. If it is possible please provide(update the question) with your updated code and what is the intention of your spider. Thanks for your patient.

Comment: The xpath in my code is for categories, I need to be able to reach every category page and get some data from them. The xpath works on scray shell, but it stops after the redirection as you can see from the output in my question.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the problem. https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/request.py .